# Find methods for MS Word

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I found a great Powershell script online which let's you search the contents of Excel documents for a specific word and I have modified it to my needs.

Now I would like to add functionality for searching the contents of Word documents, but I am struggling to figure out the methods (?) I need to use.

Forgive me if I got the terminology regarding class and method wrong, this is new ground for me.

This the the existing code for the script:

```cs
$SearchDest = Read-Host "Where do you want to search?"
$Destination = 'C:\temp'
$SearchText = 'myword'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$Files = Get-ChildItem "$SearchDest\*.xlsx" | Select-Object -Expand FullName
$counter = 1

ForEach($File in $Files) {

    Write-Progress -Activity "Checking: $file" -Status "File $counter of $($files.count)" `
                   -PercentComplete ($counter * 100 / $files.Count)

    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)

    If($Workbook.Sheets.Item(1).Range("A:Z").Find($SearchText)) {
        $Workbook.Close($false)
        Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $Destination
        "Copied $file to $destination"
        break
    }

    $Workbook.Close($false)
    $counter++
}
```

and I am trying to find out what the equivalent to `$Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)` etc. is.

Comment: Have you tried looking for Word based scripts to get the methods you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, which will loop through a folder for .docx files and search those files for a word or phrase:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")

# create a word app object
Write-Host 'creating word app object'

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True

$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Path\To\WordDocs\' -Filter '*.docx' | select -ExpandProperty Fullname

# options for the search
$findText          = 'DataFolder'   # alter this to find the word you're interested in
$matchCase         = $false
$matchWholeWord    = $true
$matchWildCards    = $false
$matchSoundsLike   = $false
$matchAllWordForms = $false
$forward           = $true
$wrap              = 1

$docs | ForEach-Object {
  $docPath = $_
  Write-Host "opening $docPath" -NoNewline

  $doc = $word.Documents.Open($docPath)

  $range = $doc.Content
  [void]$range.MoveStart()

  $wordFound = $range.Find.Execute($findText,$matchCase,$matchWholeWord,$matchWildCards,$matchSoundsLike,$matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap)

  if ($wordFound) {
    # do something meaningful here
  }
  # for now, we'll output a list of files and if the word was found
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    FilePath   = $docPath
    WordToFind = $findText
    WordFound  = $wordFound
  }

  $doc.Close()
}

# clean up after ourselves
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$word)
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable word
```

Comment: Hi Techspud, thanks for providing me with an answer to my problem. Are you able  to tell me how you figured  out which methods to use? Is there a list somewhere that lists word.application.documents etc?

Comment: Google & StackOverflow :). No, really. Google how to find a string in a word doc and there's a Scripting Guys article that gives some detail. Plus the looping, opening/closing and clean up were also gleaned from previous Google & SO searches. Can you mark as complete if this answers your question, please?